# Android add to listview

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I am trying to add list view items at the end of my ListView
the problem is that it replaces the previous list. previously I used to define the listview variable inside this procedure, but now I made it public, but still not adding the new list to the previous one.
what is that i am doing wrong here?
I tried as suggested to use .notifyDataSetChanged() but did not work
Here is my code before

```
@Override
protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... xmlData) {
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlData[0]);

    MsgsXmlParser msgsXmlParser = new MsgsXmlParser();

    List<HashMap<String, String>> msgs = null;

    try{
        msgs = msgsXmlParser.parse(reader);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
    }

    String[] from = {"Fld1", "Fld2","Fld3"};
    int[] to = {R.id.tvFld1, R.id.tvFld2, R.id.tvFld3};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), msgs, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

    return adapter;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

    lvMsgs.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

and here is after (The adapter is null )

```
SimpleAdapter adapter;
List<HashMap<String, String>> msgs = null;
String[] from = {"Fld1", "Fld2","Fld3"};
int[] to to = {R.id.tvFld1, R.id.tvFld2, R.id.tvFld3};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), msgs, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);
}



    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... xmlData) {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlData[0]);

        MsgsXmlParser msgsXmlParser = new MsgsXmlParser();


        try{
            msgs = msgsXmlParser.parse(reader);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }

        return adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lvMsgs.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SimpleAdapter` probably contains a reference to list of objects that you would like to display inside the `lvMsgs` ListView.

What you have to do is to add new items to this list of objects and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the **adapter** as described here for example: [ListView data not showing on android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22206733/listview-data-not-showing-on-android-sdk?rq=1)

```
// Lets assume you have some list of msgs and a adapter
// You could store those as class variables
List<String> msgs = new ArrayList<String>();
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, msgs, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

// Point ListView to use previously created adapter
ListView lvMsgs = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.lvMsgs);
lvMsgs.setAdapter(adapter);

// later in code do some updates to the list of objects
// and notify the adapter that it should refresh its content
msgs.add("SomeString");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope that helps somehow.

Thing to note: ListView can use **one adapter** only, that is why you have to update the msgs list and notify the adapter to update the displayed content.

Comment: Thanks, but how to add the new adapter list to the original one?             adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), msgs, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);

Comment: I tried to add the list to msgs using this code msgs.add(msgsXmlParser.parse(reader)); but I got this error   no suitable method found for add(List<HashMap<String,String>>)
method List.add(HashMap<String,String>) is not applicable

Comment: // ---------- I tried this but still does not work  


   SimpleAdapter saAdapter;
 
       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

            saAdapter = adapter;

            if (lvMsgs.getCount()==0) {
                lvMsgs.setAdapter(saAdapter);
            }
            else {
                saAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

Comment: it actually works, just need to refresh the listview some how, i mean when i start typing on the a edittext the new data showed up in the list, i think i need to refresh the interface some how

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resetting the adapter, simply call:

```
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

That will inform the list that the data changed, and the list will build items accordingly.